# How to enable debug logs in Apache Tika 2.4.0

Tags: debugging, containers, apache-tika, tika-server

Want to enable debug logs in Apache tika container. Tried following Tika config configuration through tika-config.xml, but do not see any debug logs getting printed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <server>
        <params>
            <logLevel>debug</logLevel>
            <taskTimeoutMillis>3600000</taskTimeoutMillis>
        </params>
    </server>
</properties>
```

Comment: How are you passing your custom Config file to Apache Tika in a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

There's a file `log4j2.xml` in the jar file, edit that one and put it back.

Alternatively, make your own, and use it with

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.xml
```

when starting the server.